# Archiving team System Source control

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to archive old data from MS Team System Source Control? We have up to 10,000 changesets in our TFS database, and are unlikely ever to want to go that far back, but the database files are getting ever larger. Is it possible to archive everything before a certain date (say) to reduce the size of the database? if not, taken to its logical conclusion a long lived actively developed project will eventually explode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can back up the whole TFS database and then use `destroy` command to permanently delete the source control tree. But you can do that only for whole source control paths, not specific versions.

In case there are many deleted files you can also use the same command to review the source control tree and permanently destroy these deleted files.

You will not be able to just delete old changesets because TFS stores incremental changes every time you check-in. This also implies that maybe you have large binary files stored in TFS - files larger than certain limit are not stored incrementally (thus saving space) but instead every version is stored complete.

Documentation on the command: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386005(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: So to destroy all changes before date D1, would  do

Comment: So to destroy all changes before date D1 in my tfs project MyProject, would I do "tf destroy $/MyProject;D1 /startcleanup"    and to do the same up to D1  "tf destroy $/MyProject /keephistory /stopat:D1 /startcleanup"     ?

Comment: unfortunately it does not seem to be possible to destroy changes before a date. `/stopat` argument is only meant for how long the history (not the contents) have to be kept.